# Rendering Graphviz in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, data-visualization, graphviz, powerbi-desktop, graph-visualization

I have anaconda installed on my laptop which I usually use to carry out data analysis. I am new to Power BI. Using Graphviz, I have the following image [image]

Using the Python Scripting in Power BI and the same code I use in anaconda, I have tried to show this in Power BI but I can't find a way around this.

Can anyone help with a solution or suggestion.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For someone who will be looking for a way to do this, I have found a way around it.

After reading the Microsoft Power BI document on [Creating Power BI visuals using Python in Power BI Desktop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/desktop-python-visuals), it specified that Python visuals are shown as images. To show this as an image, I saved it first to my laptop, then used matplotlib's `mpimg.imread` function to read the image immediately and display it on Power Bi.

```
filename = 'PowerBiGraphviz'

ctrlflw = Z12.render(filename, view=False)
img = mpimg.imread(ctrlflw)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20,20))
ax.imshow(img)
ax.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

Note that the visual is also responsive to filtering. Depending on your python script, the visual can take some more seconds before they come up.

The way I have been able to make it faster is to extract just the information I would need to draw my visual on Power BI and import it to Power BI in a separate table.

If you know a faster way, that information will be appreciated.